# Linear regression on mean + standard deviation

Tags: regression, estimation, unbiased-estimator

I have observations made at different times from a normally distributed real random variable whose mean and standard deviation both vary linearly with time.  How can I estimate these two linear functions?

More precisely: assume I have a dataset containing $N$ samples $(t_i,y_i)$, where each $y$ is drawn independently from a normally distributed real random variable having expected value $at+b$ and variance $(ut+v)^2$, where $a,b,u,v$ are unknown parameters.  How can I estimate $a,b,u,v$?  Are there standard estimators that will do this?

Allow me to be deliberately a bit vague as to exactly what I want from the estimators $\hat a, \hat b, \hat u, \hat v$ in question, but desirable properties would certainly be:

- being unbiased,
- having a simple explicit expression in terms of the sample means of monomials in $t$ and $y$ (i.e., $\frac{1}{N}\sum_i t_i$, $\frac{1}{N}\sum_i y_i$, $\frac{1}{N}\sum_i t_i^2$, $\frac{1}{N}\sum_i t_i y_i$, $\frac{1}{N}\sum_i y_i^2$, and possibly higher powers),
- being able to be construed as a generalization of the ordinary least squares method for simple linear regression (giving $a,b$, and together with the corrected sample standard deviation of the residuals for $v$) when $u$ is additionally assumed (or just estimated) to be $0$,
- having a standard name.

Comment: Have you attempted writing down the likelihood and solving for the MLEs?